# What is the proper way to use a PHP instance variable multiple times

Tags: php, instance-variables

I am trying to use a PHP instance variable multiple times in a method but only the first shows a value, the rest return nothing. What is the proper way to do it. See example code

```
<? class Foo{
private $variable;

  //constructor
  public function __construct($variable){
    $this->variable = $variable;
  }

  //method
  public function renderVariable(){
    echo "first use of the variable".$this->variable; //shows the variable when method is called
    echo "subsequent use of the variable".this->variable; //shows nothing
  }

}
?>
```

Assume the above class is saved as Foo.php and called below

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?
include 'Foo.php';
$x = Foo(37);
$x->renderVariable();//prints two lines, the first includes 37, the second does not
?>
</body>
```

Currently I am having to pass the instance to a local variable within the method, see below

```
<? class Foo{
private $variable;

  //constructor
  public function __construct($variable){
    $this->variable = $variable;
  }

  //method
  public function renderVariable(){
    $y=$this->variable;
    echo "first use of the variable".$y; //shows the variable when method is called
    echo "subsequent use of the variable".$y; //shows the variable when method is called
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: The second instance is probably failing because you're missing the `$` in front of `this` on ` echo "subsequent use of the variable".this->variable;`

Comment: typo `this` should be `$this`

Comment: Yes I have seen the typo, but the original code has the $

Comment: Second 'typo' is you're instantiating class `Foo` as a function, i.e. you're invoking `Foo(37);`, whereas it should be `new Foo(37);`. I reproduced, with correct syntax, output: `first use of the variable37subsequent use of the variable37`, as expected.

Comment: Thanks Lovelace!

Comment: Tip, turn on error reporting, you should have had an error along the lines of `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Foo()` And you're welcome :-)